# Add functionality to inherited property

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, design-patterns

I wish to incorporate [HTAutocompleteTextField](https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField) into my project.

The QuickStart Guide shows how to use it when creating a new textfield object

```
HTAutocompleteTextField *textField = [[HTAutocompleteTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,31)];

textField.autocompleteDataSource = [HTAutocompleteManager sharedManager];
textField.autocompleteType = HTAutocompleteTypeEmail;
```

I want to add the functionality to an existing, inherited `UITextField` e.g. `existingTextfield` in `MyViewController`.

`MyViewController` is a subclass of a `FrameWorkViewController`

What is the best way to approach this?

**EDIT** `existingTextfield` is a readonly property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your existing text field is created and initialized in the code, just create an instance of `HTAutocompleteTextField` like above, and assign it to the `existingTextField` variable. `[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` is a good place to do that.

If you're using a storyboard or a xib, open it in the Interface Builder, select existingTextField and specify **HTAutocompleteTextField** in the custom class field instead of the default value **UITextField** (see the image below). Don't forget to specify the data source, etc. for the text field in the code.

[image]

Comment: Hi BlackRider, Thanks for the comment, `existingTextField` is a readonly property

Comment: Well, then you may need to resort to some tricks. E.g. create and add your own text field, and place it on top of the existing one. You can also take the existing field's delegate and use it as the delegate for the new one. You get the idea. I would try that.

Comment: Could you explain the delegate method you suggested please?

Comment: I mean `UITextFieldDelegate`. It may or may not be implemented for this text field, and if it is there, you want it to handle events from your new text field you'll put in place of the old one. So you could do something like `myNewTextField.delegate = existingTextField.delegate;`

**BUT!*** It is very likely that your autocompleting text field already implements its own delegate (to watch for new input from the user). That would be a problem for trying to do what you want.